# Create Database Permission on Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Im trying to assign Create Database Permission to one of User Account in Azure SQL DW but its giving error while trying to execute it.

Tsql:

```
grant alter any database to [test_user1]
```

Error:

```
Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Please let me know if this permission (Create Database) can be used in Azure SQL DW

Comment: Are you looking for CREATE or ALTER database permission? Create permissions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest#permissions